# Comparing and flipping adjacent values in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, scipy, vectorization

I want to compare adjacent values in a (potentially multi-dimensional) `bool` numpy array such that if there are adjacent `True` values in a row, only the leftmost would be kept while the rest would be flipped to `False`. For example:

```
Input:  [True, False, False, True]
Output: [True, False, False, True]

Input:  [True, True, False, True]
Output: [True, False, False, True]

Input:  [True, True, True, True]
Output: [True, False, False, False]
```

Is there an efficient (i.e. vectorized) way of achieving this in NumPy, SciPy, or TensorFlow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the *logical_and* of the array with its shifted version, if both true, flip the values:

```
a[np.concatenate(([False], a[:-1])) & a] = False
```

*Testing*:

```
a = np.array([True, True, True, True])
a[np.concatenate(([False], a[:-1])) & a] = False       
a
# array([ True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

a = np.array([True, True, False, True])    
a[np.concatenate(([False], a[:-1])) & a] = False    
a
# array([ True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)

a = np.array([True, False, False, True])
a[np.concatenate(([False], a[:-1])) & a] = False 
a
# array([ True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a 1-d array:

```
a = np.array([True, True, False, True])
b = np.diff(a)
a[1:] = np.logical_and(a[1:], b)

>>> a
array([ True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>>
```